# .Net Config supported runtime element issue

Tags: .net, configuration

I have one application which is always crashing when below element is there in config file. If we remove this element application is working fine.

I have .Net Ver 4.0 is installed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Please advice

Comment: Then why do you need it there? And shouldn't it be `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />`?

Comment: It is third party application. Samsung Kies